# Image sprites not rendering properly for retina

Tags: css, retina-display, sprite

On this site: http://goo.gl/VNct8O I made a widget for available payment methods. All the logos in it are expected to be retina ready. 
I used coolrunnings to develop the sprites using spriteme service.

However, when I zoom to 200% in chrome all logos looks stretched. Positions are correct, just the images are stretched. How can understand what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a ton of experience with Retina but this might help, i think you need to use a media query for it

```
 @media 
 (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
 (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
 /* Retina-specific stuff here */
 }
```

Here is a good article about it http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `background-size` to `64px 584px;` on your `ul.accepted-payment-methods li.american-express span` class resolves the stretching.  From there, just adjust each payment type's `background-position` and you should be good to go.